# i7 720qm and intel integrated video card

Tags: graphics-card, intel-core-i7

couple of years ago I bought a dell N5010 laptop. It works on HM57 chipset and has integrated intel video card.

Recently I bought i7 720qm cpu and tried to replace my old cpu, but nothing really worked out. Computer doesn't boot, display is turned off all the time. I read somewhere that i7 chipsets need dedicated video card. Is it true?

Comment: "Tried to replace my old CPU" What did you do? did you actually remove it from the mobo? It may not even be supported by this. Your laptop may possibly be toast here

Comment: Well, I just removed old cpu from the socket and put the new one, when it didn't work out I removed the new one and put the old one back and everything worked well

Comment: I also checked motherboard chipset compatibility with i7 720qm and its compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Your old processor has to be a i7 of 600 or lower series or a i3/i5, the matter is that these processors have integrated gpu on the same chip. Particularly the i7 (clarskfield) doesn't have a gpu on the processor chip so that is the reason of your display turned off all time, it cant turn on because there is no video card on your laptop.

I think that your laptop cant handle an external video card (there are some solutions using the express card bus to connect an external video card, you can search in google under those concepts, but is completely unpractical). The highest processor that your laptop can handle is a i7-600 series, those processors have a intel hd graphics on the chip (arrandale architecture).